# bash csv file column extraction and deduplication

Tags: bash, csv, awk, grep

I have a .csv file I am working with and I need to output another csv file that contains a de-deuplicated list of columns 2 and 6 from the first csv with some caveats.
This is a bit difficult to explain in words but here is an example of what my input is:

```
"customer_name","cid”,”boolean_status”,”type”,”number”
“conotoso, inc.”,”123456”,”TRUE”,”Inline”,”210”
"conotoso, inc.","123456”,”FALSE”,”Inline”,”411"
“afakename”,”654321”,”TRUE","Inline”,”253”
“bfakename”,”909090”,”FALSE”,”Inline”,”321”
“cfakename”,”121212”,”TRUE","Inline","145”
```

what I need for this to do is create a new .csv file containing only "customer_name" column and "boolean_status" column.
Now, I also need there to be only one line for "customer_name" and to show "TRUE" if ANY of the customer_name matches a "true" value in the boolean column.

The output from the above input should be this:

```
"customer_name",”boolean_status”
“conotoso, inc.”,”TRUE”
“afakename”,”TRUE"
“cfakename”,”TRUE"
```

So far I tried

```
awk -F "\"*\",\"*\"" '{print $1","$6}' data1.csv >data1out.csv
```

to give me the output file, but then I attempted to `cat data1out.csv | grep 'TRUE'` with no good luck

can someone help me out on what i should do to manipulate this properly?
I'm also running into issues with the awk printing out the leading commas

All I really need at the end is a number of "how many unique 'customer_names' have at least 1 'True' in the "boolean" column?"

Comment: Given the `,` in some of your customer names, using `awk -F,` is going to be a problem.

Comment: following up on above, can you get an alternate Field Separator? The `tab` is a good one, or `|` is seldom found in clean account level data. Then it will be easy to provide the output AND if really needed, you could output with `,` column separators. (Some day I'll write a "(truly) comma-separated data considered harmful manifesto ;-/ ). Good luck.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do it using `awk`? This is pretty trivial to do in more complex languages and I wonder if there is any purpose wasting time to get it to work with `awk/grep/sh`. I'm pretty certain it would even be more performant in, say, Python than doing multiple procedural lookaheads/lookbehinds that you'd need to do with `awk`....

Comment: to answer the aboves, this data is generated from another source that I am not able to get changed, I really wanted it to be something else as well, or at least get the inputs sanitized so i don't have to worry about commas in the names.
Additionally, the environment I have to work on is limited to bash, I would love to do this in Python as that's my main lang but again, limited to bash out of my control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get your de duplicated file by using

`sort -u -t, -k2,2 -k6,6 filname>sortedfile`

Post this you can write a script to extract the columns required.

```
while read line
 do
 grep "TRUE" "$line"
  if [ $? -eq 0]
  then
  a=$(cut -d',' -f1-f3 $line)
  echo a >>outputfile
   fi
   done<<sortedfile
```

Comment: sort function did a pretty good clean up job, though if a customer had both TRUE and FALSE values in the boolean column then it ends up dedeuping it down to two lines, one with TRUE, one with FALSE, but this is a big help already, i'm actually thinking i may be able to accomplish what i'm looking for by splitting this into two lists, one of all trues, then creating a list by matching all TRUEs to the first list and removing all matches. I should be left with nothing but customers who only have FALSE values in boolean clumn

Comment: further along, i used your above sort command to create deduped.csv

I used 'cut -d, -f1,6 <deduped.csv' to get a 2 column file of just "customer_name","boolean"
This should make it easier to then split off only TRUEs and then delete them from the main list

Comment: so the bash script needed a bit of syntax fixing for those reading, but it does the trick:

`while read line; do
  grep -qi "true" <(echo "${line}") || continue
  a=$(cut -d',' -f1,3)
  echo $a > ./dowhile.csv
done <"${file}"`

Comment: Will fix the syntax once i get the system.. and i love how compact your script is